# PrimeFaces Button's Background image doesn't display after version upgrade

Tags: primefaces

We have recently upgraded Primeface version from 4.0 to 5.0. But background image of UI components doesn't display correctly. It appears as below image,

[image]

Theme configuration in web.xml is,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Background image should be visible as below image,

[image]

I inspected the URL of the background image, CSS is,

```
enter code here
background: #c6deff url("#{resource['primefaces-bluesky:images/default.png']}") repeat-x;
```

Comment: Did you inspect CSS with browser tools or by looking in the theme jar?

Comment: @Vsevolod Golovanov : Yes I did, computed CSS is, 
background-color: rgb(198, 222, 255);
background-image: url(http://<website URL>/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bluesky);
background-origin: padding-box;

Comment: I would expect `.../javax.faces.resource/images/default.png?ln=primefaces-bluesky` inside the computed css.

Comment: Yes that's the url should be, I don't understand why URL is generated as .../javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bluesky